# On the residues of $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{-n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Define $f_{n}(z)=(z-z_0)^{-n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Notice that $f_n$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z=z_0$, for every positive integer $n$.

**My question:** Does $f$ has residue $0$ at $z=z_0$ for every positive integer $n$?

Unless i'm mistaken, this seems to be the case, since

$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n} f}{dz^{n}} (z-z_0)^n  (z-z_0)^{-n}=0$

for every positive integer $n.$

Comment: There will be a non-zero residue for $n = 1$, and a zero residue for all other integers $n$.

Comment: The formula to compute the residue at an $n$th order pole is
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f,z_0) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left( (z-z_0)^n f(z) \right)
$$
note that for $n=1$, we're taking a "zeroeth derivative"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The residue is $1$ if $n=1$ (and $0$ on all other cases). Your formula is wrong. It should be $\frac{\mathrm d^{n-1}f}{\mathrm dx^{n-1}}$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm d^nf}{\mathrm dx^n}$.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The residue at a point $z_0$ of some function it is just the coefficient $c_{-1}$ of the Laurent expansion of the function around $z_0$. A Laurent expansion in an annulus around $z=z_0$ for some function $g$ have the form

$$g(z):=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} c_k (z-z_0)^k$$

In your case $f_n$ is already in the form of a Laurent series around $z_0$ such that $c_k=0$ for all $k\neq -n$ and $c_{-n}=1$. Then $f_n$ have residue zero at $z_0$ for each $n\neq 1$, and for $f_1$ we have that $c_{-1}=1$, so the residue of $f_1$ at $z_0$ is $1$.